# What is the best way to see if a RadioButtonList has a selected value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, radiobuttonlist

I am using:

```
if (RadioButtonList_VolunteerType.SelectedItem != null)
```

or how about:

```
if (RadioButtonList_VolunteerType.Index >= 0)
```

or how about (per Andrew Hare's answer):

```
if (RadioButtonList_VolunteerType.Index > -1)
```

To those who may read this question, **the following is not a valid method**.  As Keltex pointed out, the selected value could be an empty string.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RadioButtonList_VolunteerType.SelectedValue))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In terms of readability they all lack something for me. This seems like a good candidate for an extension method.

```
public static class MyExtenstionMethods 
{   
  public static bool HasSelectedValue(this RadioButtonList list) 
  {
    return list.SelectedItem != null;
  }
}


...

if (RadioButtonList_VolunteerType.HasSelectedValue)
{
 // do stuff
}
```

Comment: By the way, it should be "return list.SelectedItem != null".

Answer (score 12):

Those are all valid and perfectly legitimate ways of checking for a selected value.  Personally I find

```
RadioButtonList_VolunteerType.SelectedIndex > -1
```

to be the clearest.

Answer (score 1):

The question revolves more around whether to check for null or check value of an int.  Martin's great extension method could also be written:

```
public static bool HasSelectedValue(this ListControl list)
{
    return list.SelectedIndex >= 0;
}
```

The MSDN documentation for a ListControl states:

> Default for [SelectedItem is null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem.aspx).
>
> Default for [SelectedIndex is -1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindex.aspx).

So either are valid ways and both work.  The question is which is the best way.  I'm guessing SelectedIndex as it is a value type operation rather than reference type operation.  But I don't have anything to back that up with.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend:

```
RadioButtonList_VolunteerType.SelectedIndex>=0.
```

According to the [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindex.aspx):

> The lowest ordinal index of the selected items in the list. The default is -1, which indicates that nothing is selected.

string.IsNullOrEmpty(RadioButtonList_VolunteerType.SelectedValue) will **not always work** as you can have a ListItem with an empty value:

```
<asp:ListItem Value=''>This item has no value</asp:ListItem>
```