# how to check radiobuttonlist selected or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist, selectedvalue, selectedindexchanged

I'm new to asp.net and c#. Trying to check radiobutton is selected or not selected. if it selected else clause will work if it's not selected want to set lbl_hata with "EMPTY!!" text.

I have also tried selectedIndexChanged and it didn't work.
How can I solve this situation?

```
if (RadioButtonList_gorusmeYapilanOkul.SelectedValue == "")
{
    lbl_hata.Text = "EMPTY!!";
}
if (yetkiliAdSoyad_txt.Text=="")
{
    lbl_hata.Text = "EMPTY!!";
}
```

This is aspx page;

```
<td class="auto-style2">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList_gorusmeYapilanOkul" runat="server" Width="174px" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="Seyrantepe Şube 1">Seyrantepe Şube 1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Seyrantepe Şube 2">Seyrantepe Şube 2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</td>
```

Comment: You're missing a `"` after `lbl_hata.Text = "EMPTY!`, probably this wan't the error because you edited your post?

Comment: I have missed " write here. but it has in my code. and dont work.

Comment: Please explain: dont work.

Comment: my else clause insert data in mysql. when i look my db after run project if clause doesnt check radio button is selected or not selected so else clause work and insert data in db.

Comment: _"else clause will work"_ you have no `else`. What is the value of `RadioButtonList_gorusmeYapilanOkul.SelectedValue` when you debug?

Comment: value of RadioButtonList_gorusmeYapilanOkul.SelectedValue is just ""

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to see if a RadioButtonList has a selected value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735775/what-is-the-best-way-to-see-if-a-radiobuttonlist-has-a-selected-value)

Answer (score 0):

selectedIndexChanged is an event that will be fired (called) when the user selects a radio button in the group.

It should like you are trying to check whether RadioButtonList_gorusmeYapilanOkul has a selected option or not. I assume this is on a different event (like the user has clicked on a button). If this is the case you don't need to trap the selectedIndexChanged event.

I would suggest you use some code like the following:

```
if (RadioButtonList_gorusmeYapilanOkul.SelectedValue == "")
{
    lbl_hata.Text = "EMPTY!!";
}
else
{
    lbl_hata.Text = "Not empty!!";
}
```

Then put a breakpoint on the first line and walk through using the debugger, this will allow you to get an understanding of what is happening and how the logic flows.

UPDATE:
I don't want to post this as a comment because it would lose formatting. 
Can you try the following code:

```
if (RadioButtonList_gorusmeYapilanOkul.SelectedIndex > -1) 
{  
    lbl_hata.Text = "You selected: " + RadioButtonList_gorusmeYapilanOkul.SelectedItem.Text;
}
else
{
    lbl_hata.Text = "You didn't select anything";
}
```

Comment: I did what you said. First select one Radio Button List Item and fire with button if clause shows  selected value correctly.  But lbl_hata.Text was not  setted "Not Empty!!".
Something goes wrong but i couldn't understand.

Comment: Can you just confirm if you put a breakpoint on both lbl_hata.Text lines which one is run? Is the lbl_hata text changed at all? Try the initial value to something like 'not run' to begin with.